# Capture ScreenShoot navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have this code that makes perfect screenshots. No tabs, no toolbars.
The only problem is the notice at the bottom. View image.

I added a one second delay before capturing. Hide the permissions window, but not the bottom window.

Is there a way to hide that little bottom window?
And by the way, hide the mouse icon.

[image: Highlight the window that should not appear in red.]

```
const capture = async () => {
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        const video = document.createElement("video");
      
        try {
          const captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
          video.srcObject = captureStream;
          await new Promise((resolve) => {
            video.onloadedmetadata = resolve;
          });
      
          await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // Esperar 1 segundo
          video.play();
      
          const displayWidth = window.innerWidth;
          const displayHeight = window.innerHeight;
          const screenLeft = window.screenLeft;
          const screenTop = window.screenTop;
          const windowLeft = window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth - screenLeft;
          const windowTop = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight - screenTop;
      
          canvas.width = displayWidth;
          canvas.height = displayHeight;
          context.drawImage(video, windowLeft, windowTop, displayWidth, displayHeight, 0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);
      
          const frame = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          captureStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
      
          if (window === window.top) {
            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = frame;
            link.download = "screenshot.png";
            link.click();
          } else {
            console.error("Error: La ventana de permisos fue capturada. No se guarda la captura.");
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("Error: " + err);
        }
      };

      capture();
```

Comment: **Question:** Are you using remote desktop software to share the screen ? Please let us know

Comment: NO, it's just a function that I want to implement in my application.
Right click, Tools, Capture Screen.
Check it out. https://artdraw.org/svg/app.html